# Loop inside the loop - python

Tags: python

I want to get highest quantity sold for s specific product id and I'm stuck.  I don't know how to add another loop that will calculate total quantity of each product id.

Below is the code and the XML file.  Thank you in advance.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

orders = root.findall("./orders")
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    total = 0
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productid = detail.findall("./products/productid")
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")
        total += float(quantity[0].text)

print total
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<nwind>


-<orders another="Friday" orderid="10248">


-<customers>

<companyname>Vins et alcools Chevalier</companyname>

<customerid>VINET</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>72</productid>

<productname>Mozzarella di Giovanni</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>34.8</unitprice>

<quantity>5</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>14</supplierid>

<companyname>Formaggi Fortini s.r.l.</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>11</productid>

<productname>Queso Cabrales</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>14</unitprice>

<quantity>12</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>5</supplierid>

<companyname>Cooperativa de Quesos 'Las Cabras'</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>42</productid>

<productname>Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>9.8</unitprice>

<quantity>10</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>20</supplierid>

<companyname>Leka Trading</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>


-<orders orderid="10249">


-<customers>

<companyname>Toms Spezialitaten</companyname>

<customerid>TOMSP</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>14</productid>

<productname>Tofus</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>18.6</unitprice>

<quantity>9</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>6</supplierid>

<companyname>Mayumi's</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>51</productid>

<productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>42.4</unitprice>

<quantity>40</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>24</supplierid>

<companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>


-<orders orderid="10250">


-<customers>

<companyname>Hanari Carnes</companyname>

<customerid>HANAR</customerid>

</customers>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>65</productid>

<productname>Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>16.8</unitprice>

<quantity>15</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>2</supplierid>

<companyname>New Orleans Cajun Delights</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>41</productid>

<productname>Jack's New England Clam Chowder</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>7.7</unitprice>

<quantity>10</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>19</supplierid>

<companyname>New England Seafood Cannery</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>


-<orderdetails>


-<products>

<productid>51</productid>

<productname>Manjimup Dried Apples</productname>

</products>

<unitprice>42.4</unitprice>

<quantity>35</quantity>


-<suppliers>

<supplierid>24</supplierid>

<companyname>G'day, Mate</companyname>

</suppliers>

</orderdetails>

</orders>

</nwind>
```

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.ElementTree(file="nwind_medium.xml")

from collections import Counter
orders = root.findall("./orders")
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    total = {}
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productid = detail.findall("./products/productid")
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")
        if productid in total.keys():
            total[product ]+=float(quantity[0].text)
        else:
            total[productid ]=float(quantity[0].text)

print Counter(total).most_common(1)

Comment: Hi, the code proceed without any error this time.  It gave me [('51',35.0)] as an output.  What if I only want the "51" as an output printout.  I only want this because this is the one with highest quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
total = {}
for order in orders:
    orderdetails = order.findall("./orderdetails")
    for detail in orderdetails:
        productid = detail.findall("./products/productid")[0].text
        quantity = detail.findall("./quantity")

        if productid in total.keys():
            total[productid]+=float(quantity[0].text)
        else:

            total[productid]=float(quantity[0].text)         

print "Higest Total Product id:",Counter(total).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

explantion:(To learn [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))

1. First intalise dictonary . for each productid as key and quantity as value
2. if product id is already present then add the present quantity with quantity in productid
3. counter is used to get maximum value ie the product id with most quantity

Comment: I'm getting the error "unhashable type: 'list' under "total[productid ]=float(quantity[0].text)

Comment: I did try to change the quantity on the XML file but for some reason, it is still giving me 51 even though I change a higher quantity on a different product id.  I changed the one on the top.

Comment: @user_new_in_python can u provide me proper example file.

Comment: I don't know how to attached file in here (new in stack overflow) but the XML file is the one at the bottom of my initial question.  I posted the whole thing.  Thank you.

Comment: nataraj Сундар is the pasted XML works for you or you need me to send you the file?

Comment: Hi, the answer you provided me seems correct except for the last line which is printing the most common.  I'm not that familiar with counter yet but I need the syntax to print the productid with the highest quantity.  Thank you.

Comment: I just pasted the XML again.  Thank you

Comment: That thing works like a charm now.  Thanks a lot.  One more thing, if I want print the Product name and Supplier ID.  Which part in the loop will I insert that? I tried to define under "order details" then define it on the if else statement but won't work.  Basically, instead of the number "51" I want to print Manjimup Dried apples and G'day, Mate